# Is there a way to preview a compose function with a StateFlow parameter?

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

Here is my function header:

```
@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
fun ListPreference(
    title: String = "Title",
    currentValue: StateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("C"),
    @PreviewParameter(PreviewTypesProvider::class) types: List<ListPreference>,
    onSelected: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    val secondaryText by currentValue.collectAsState()
```

When it tries to render the preview, I get an error. If I remove the `currentValue` parameter (and comment out its usage), it renders successfully. Is there a way to get the the preview to work with a `StateFlow` parameter?

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableMethod(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:149)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.CommonPreviewUtils.invokeComposableViaReflection$ui_tooling_release(CommonPreviewUtils.kt:188)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:571)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1$composable$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:569)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:608)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.InspectableKt.Inspectable(Inspectable.kt:64)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:513)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$WrapPreview$1.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:512)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:508)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter.access$WrapPreview(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:121)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:564)
> at androidx.compose.ui.tooling.ComposeViewAdapter$init$3.invoke(ComposeViewAdapter.kt:561)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:228)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView$ensureCompositionCreated$1.invoke(ComposeView.android.kt:227)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.CompositionLocalsKt.ProvideCommonCompositionLocals(CompositionLocals.kt:148)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:114)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt$ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals$3.invoke(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:113)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidCompositionLocals_androidKt.ProvideAndroidCompositionLocals(AndroidCompositionLocals.android.kt:106)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:162)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1$3.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionLocalKt.CompositionLocalProvider(CompositionLocal.kt:215)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:161)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerKt.invokeComposable(Composer.kt:3330)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2577)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$doCompose$2$5.invoke(Composer.kt:2573)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.SnapshotStateKt.observeDerivedStateRecalculations(SnapshotState.kt:540)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.doCompose(Composer.kt:2566)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl.composeContent$runtime_release(Composer.kt:2517)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.composeContent(Composition.kt:476)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:727)
> at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:432)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:144)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.setOnViewTreeOwnersAvailable(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:727)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.setContent(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition.onStateChanged(Wrapper.android.kt:187)
> at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
> at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:142)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.WrappedComposition$setContent$1.invoke(Wrapper.android.kt:135)
> at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onAttachedToWindow(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:814)
> at android.view.View.dispatchAttachedToWindow(View.java:20479)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3489)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchAttachedToWindow(ViewGroup.java:3496)
> at android.view.AttachInfo_Accessor.setAttachInfo(AttachInfo_Accessor.java:44)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:360)
> at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:431)
> at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:141)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:714)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:870)
> at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$2.run(RenderExecutor.kt:187)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)

Answer (score 2):

You can define a custom [`PreviewParameter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/tooling/preview/PreviewParameter) implementing the interface [**`PreviewParameterProvider`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/tooling/preview/PreviewParameterProvider).

Something like:

```
class SampleStateFlowProvider: PreviewParameterProvider<MutableStateFlow<String>> {
    override val values = sequenceOf(MutableStateFlow("A"),MutableStateFlow("D"))
    override val count: Int = values.count()
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun ListPreferencePreview(@PreviewParameter(SampleStateFlowProvider::class) stateFlow: MutableStateFlow<String>) {
    ListPreference("Title", stateFlow, {/*...*/})
}

@Composable
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterialApi::class)
fun ListPreference(
    title: String = "Title",
    currentValue: StateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("C"),
    onSelected: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
) {
    val secondaryText by currentValue.collectAsState()

    //..Text(currentValue.value)
}
```

[image]

Comment: My understanding is that the preferred pattern is to do "[state hoisting](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/state#state-hoisting)". With that, rather than passing the flow as parameter, you pass a list to your stateless function